# List of strings replace each instance of a certain value in each string with another value

Tags: python

I have a list of times of events in strings (i.e. ['Apr 24th 10:00 p.m.','Apr 26th 7:00 p.m.']).
I'd like to replace each instance of the number 10 with the number 7, 8 with the number 5 etc. Is there any way to have a list of values (i.e. [10,9,8,7,6,5]) that wherever one of those values is found in a string then that value is replaced with the value with the same index in another list (i.e. [7,6,5,4,3]). Essentially I'd like to loop through the items in my list and replace every instance of a number with the time 3 hours prior to it.
This was my stab at it but I believe there's a cleaner way of doing it.

```
for x in resulter:
                y=x.split(':')
                first=y[0][:-1]
                hour=y[0][-1]
                end=y[1]
                new_hour=int(hour)-3
                newtime=first+str(new_hour)+':'+ end
                new_western_times.append(newtime)
            newer_western_times=[string.replace('1-3', '7') for string in new_western_times]
            newest_western_times=[string.replace('0:', '12:') for string in newer_western_times]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a cleaner way to do it. Also, it will prevent many headeaches, such as changing PM to AM or changing the date, things like that. Instead of manipulating the string, simply use the datetime package.

First, you need to modify your strings so they can be in a format that can be recognized as a datetime. There are two things that cause an issue at the moment:

- The ordinal dates
- The dots for AM and PM

You can remove both in one line using a little regex.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re


def sanitize_string(s: str) -> str:
  """
  Takes a string and removes all instances of "st", "nd", "rd", "th" that
   follows a digit and all instances of the dot character in the string to
   prepare the string for a conversion to a datetime object.

  @s: The original datetime string.
  returns: the sanitized string.
  """
  return re.sub(r"((\d)(st|nd|rd|th|)|\.)", "\\2", s)

original_strings = ['Apr 24th 10:00 p.m.','Apr 26th 7:00 p.m.']
sanitized_strings = [sanitize_string(s) for s in original_strings]

print(sanitized_strings)

# ['Apr 24 10:00 pm', 'Apr 26 7:00 pm']
```

Then, we convert the strings to datetime objects.

```
datetimes = [datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d %I:%M %p") for s in sanitized_strings]

print(datetimes)

# [datetime.datetime(1900, 4, 24, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 4, 26, 19, 0)]
```

Then, we can remove three hours by using timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta

new_datetimes = [d - timedelta(hours=3) for d in datetimes]

print(new_datetimes)

# [datetime.datetime(1900, 4, 24, 19, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 4, 26, 16, 0)]
```

Don't worry about the format being different because the next step would be to convert those datetimes back to strings, using the same format.

```
new_strings = [d.strftime("%b %d %I:%M %p") for d in new_datetimes]

print(new_strings)

# ['Apr 24 07:00 PM', 'Apr 26 04:00 PM']
```

Of course, you're not bound to use the same format and you can even put back the ordinals or the dots for AM and PM if you really want to.

Last point, I use a lot of list comprehensions to better explain each point, but that's not how I would to do it. I would put everything in a method and simply use a list comprehension with that method once. Like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re


def sanitize_string(s: str) -> str:
  """
  Takes a string and removes all instances of "st", "nd", "rd", "th" that
   follows a digit and all instances of the dot character in the string to
   prepare the string for a conversion to a datetime object.
  """
  return re.sub(r"((\d)(st|nd|rd|th|)|\.)", "\\2", s)

def remove_3_hours(s: str) -> str:
  """
  Takes a string in the following formats, "Apr 24th 10:00 p.m." or "Apr 24  
   10:00 PM" and returns a string in the same format, but with 3 hours 
   removed, such as "Apr 24 7:00 pm".
  """
  datetime_format = "%b %d %I:%M %p"
  s = sanitize_string(s)
  d = datetime.strptime(s, datetime_format) - timedelta(hours=3)
  return d.strftime(datetime_format)

original_strings = ['Apr 24th 10:00 p.m.','Apr 26th 7:00 p.m.']
new_strings = [remove_3_hours(s) for s in original_strings]

print(new_strings)

# ['Apr 24 07:00 PM', 'Apr 26 04:00 PM']
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually trying to increment the hours as integers, it would be better to use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library.  We can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find and substitute the occurrences.

Example solution:

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def num_suffix(num: int) -> str:
    if 3 < num < 21:
        return 'th'
    suffixes = {'1': 'st', '2': 'nd', '3': 'rd'}
    return suffixes.get(str(num)[-1:], 'th')


def fix_date(match) -> str:
    """Fix a single date."""
    # Reformat the date so it can be parsed, and parse it
    dt = datetime.strptime(match.group(1) + match.group(2) + 'm', '%b %d %I:%M %p')
    dt -= timedelta(hours=3)         # Subtract 3 hours
    
    month = dt.strftime('%b')        # New month abbreviation
    day_suffix = num_suffix(dt.day)  # New day suffix in case the day changed
    
    time_str = dt.strftime('%I:%M %p').lower()[:-1]
    if time_str.startswith('0'):
        # Remove the leading 0 to match the original format
        time_str = time_str[1:]
    
    return f'{month} {dt.day}{day_suffix} {time_str}'


def fix_all_dates(text: str) -> str:
    """Fix all occurrences of dates in the given text to be 3 hours earlier"""
    # Capture the month and day, ignoring the day suffix.
    # Capture the hour, minute, and first char of AM/PM since the 'a.m.' format is not accepted by strptime
    pat = re.compile(r'([a-z]{3} \d{1,2})[snrt][tdh]( \d{1,2}:\d{2} [ap])', re.IGNORECASE)
    # Update the text, using the fix_date function to handle substitutions
    return pat.sub(fix_date, text)
```

Using the following example text:

```py
text = """\
foo Apr 24th 10:00 p.m. bar
bar Apr 26th 7:00 p.m. baz
baz Nov 1st 1:00 a.m. foo
"""
```

Example output:

```py
>>> print(fix_all_dates(text))
foo Apr 24th 7:00 p.m. bar
bar Apr 26th 4:00 p.m. baz
baz Oct 31st 10:00 p.m. foo
```

If you already have the timestamps in a list of strings, then the same function would still work:

```py
>>> dt_strs = ['Apr 24th 10:00 p.m.', 'Apr 26th 7:00 p.m.', 'Nov 1st 1:00 a.m.']

>>> fixed = [fix_all_dates(d) for d in dt_strs]

>>> fixed
['Apr 24th 7:00 p.m.', 'Apr 26th 4:00 p.m.', 'Oct 31st 10:00 p.m.']
```

Note that last date there - it correctly handled rolling over midnight and over a month boundary as well.

This solution used the form of [`Pattern.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub) that accepts a function to provide the substitution.  For the syntax of the regex pattern, you can learn more here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

The format codes for the datetime parsing/formatting can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).